# Rails with Redshift - how do I create relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-redshift

In my Rails App I'm trying to get a Redshift storage for one of my models. I have proper settings like

```
class RedshiftBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :redshift_development
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

and

```
class Books < RedshiftBase
  self.table_name = :books
end
```

so my `Book.connection` returns valid `#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::RedshiftAdapter:0...` object. Still I have no idea where do I go from here so I get relation which will update Redshift db each time I create an object (`Book.new` returns `PG::UndefinedTable:` error so far).

Comment: Try to test `books` table like `Book.connection.execute('select count(*) from books')`. There is a chance you have `books` not in `public` namespace.

Comment: The thing is that I can not create valid relation in RedShift (do not know how). I can do things like  `Book.connection.create_table(:books)` and I will get a relation BUT is that a way to do it? How do I create attributes?

Comment: What is "relation" exactly? If it is a table, have you used Active Record Migrations to create it?

Comment: Yes, I have a migration but after running it my redshift DB doesn't get updated with a new table

Comment: So you have to solve issue with the migration. Permissions, wrong DB, whatever.

Comment: It might help to post the schema.

Comment: Please post your database.yml file

Comment: What happens when you run the migration - please upload the output? Have you tried db:reset?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using either of these gems to tie it into 
ActiveRecord:

[Rails 5 ActiveRecord Redshift Adapter](https://github.com/ConsultingMD/activerecord5-redshift-adapter)

[Rails 4 ActiveRecord Redshift Adapter](https://github.com/aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter)

---

Or For Manual Connections:

[Create Redshift Client Connection via PG](https://github.com/dakatsuka/redshift-client)